# How to deploy a springboot - war - to - Google AppEngine - Java11

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, java-11

I am trying to deploy a war packaged springboot app - Java 11

Created a brand new springboot web application (packaging war) and followed article https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/war-packaging
from step1 . i.e. cloning and installing (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples)

spring boot parent

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<!--        <version>2.7.2</version>-->
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
<!--                <version>2.0.3</version>-->
                <version>2.0.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Excluding tomcat from web

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.appengine.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-jetty-main</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and plugins

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <version>1</version>
            <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/appengine-staging
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

src/main/appengine/app.yaml

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" com.example.appengine.demo.jettymain.Main myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war'
instance_class: B2

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 20
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 0.5
```

Output :

[image]

Sadly this is not what I am expecting.

**Another Variation:**
I remembered servlet initalizer is not added, so correct it

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DashApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.runDashApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DashApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**Error**:

Application thows error in the logs

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate
> org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor
> [org.springframework.boot.test.web.SpringBootTestRandomPortEnvironmentPostProcessor]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:131)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)

What is my mistake ?

Please help - How to create a simple Java 11 , springboot , war package, and deploy to appengine

Comment: I made some tweaks, and found that  I need to add test dependency without scope as test  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>      
    </dependency>

Comment: Hi @Kris Swat, you can post the changes you've made as an answer so that it will be visible to the community.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments section, adding `spring-boot-starter-test` as test dependency in pom.xml fixed the issue.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Comment: Note: I had to remove <scope>test</scope> for spring-boot-starter-test . My application worked for an year on Appengine and because of some changes by google, the app is no longer starting. I no longer use AppEngine. So didn't answer the question (honestly, I made too many changes to give details). I am sure AppEngine will change again and work properly